# Dynamic Table won't add any rows

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a dynamic table that I'm trying to make show up on the screen. It's created from parsing an xml string that is returned from a web service. However, it runs through the code with no errors but it's just not adding any rows to the table for me...

```
public void createTable(String xmlForTable) 
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {


    Integer i = 0;
    endPlacementTag = "nothing";


     lo = (TableLayout)  findViewById(R.id.tiresTable);

     TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
     TableRow.LayoutParams hp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     headerRow.setLayoutParams(hp);

     tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText("Text Header");
     headerRow.addView(tv);
     lo.addView(headerRow);

     XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput(new StringReader (xmlForTable));
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

     TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

        rfid = new TextView(this);
        projectNumber = new TextView(this);
        inspectionLotNumber = new TextView(this);
        serialization = new TextView(this);
        spec = new TextView(this);
        sku = new TextView(this);
        materialNumber = new TextView(this);


     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {



          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("Start document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("End document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
              placementTag = xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
              endPlacementTag = "End tag "+xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());




              //If the text tag is equal to "Table" do nothing otherwise...
              if(placementTag.equals("Table"))
              {
                  //Do Nothing
              }

              else if(placementTag.equals("Serialization"))
              {
                  serialization.setText(xpp.getText());
                  serialization.setTextSize(10);
                  serialization.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                  //row.addView(serialization);
                  placementTag = "";

              }

             ... //Other if statements

              else if(endPlacementTag.equals("End tag Table")) 
              {

                  row.addView(rfid);
                  row.addView(projectNumber);
                  row.addView(inspectionLotNumber);
                  row.addView(serialization);
                  row.addView(spec);
                  row.addView(sku);
                  row.addView(materialNumber);

                  row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                  row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  lo.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  //i++;
                  row.removeAllViews();
                  lo.removeAllViews();

              }

              }
          eventType = xpp.next();
          }
```

I have set the params like I have read in other examples on SO, and I made sure that I had the `import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;` imported rather than `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I think the above constructor is not what you are looking for. The above is

```
public TableRow.LayoutParams (int column)
Puts the view in the specified column.
Sets the child width to MATCH_PARENT and the child height to WRAP_CONTENT.
```

You probably wanted to use this one:

```
public TableRow.LayoutParams (int w, int h)
Sets the child width and height.
```

Like this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I implemented your code and it still does not show any of the data in my data

Comment: Why are you calling removeAllViews at the end? You are already creating a new row each time.

Comment: Cause if I don't do that then I get an error:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`